# Checking whether null value received from get()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an object which I receive from an API. Now I want to display a particular value from the object, but if the value is null, it should be blank by using get().

Consider the object as below:

```
const person = {
firstName:"John", 
lastName:"Doe", 
petName: null,
age:50, 
eyeColor:"blue"};
```

Say I am displaying the value of Pet Name only if I received an object from the API.
But I do not want to display 'NULL', instead, it should be blank.

```
<Box>{`Pet Name: ${ person ? get(person, 'petName') : '' }`}</Box>
```

The output => Pet Name: null

Instead, want the output to be => Pet Name:(it should be blank if null, else the value)

Comment: what data does ```person``` contain when you init it on your code?

Comment: `person.petName ?? ''` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: `get(person, 'petName') ?? ''`

Comment: What about `person && get(person, 'petName') || ''`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
<Box>{`Pet Name: ${ person ? get(person, 'petName') ?? '' : '' }`}</Box>
```

Comment: if I want to add a small string like 'MR'  or 'MISS' just before the name is displayed, what will it be. Like Pet Name: Miss Rose

Comment: @ParulRanjan That won't work with nullish coalescing.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix that. Add one more conditional statement.

```
<Box>{`Pet Name: ${ person ? get(person, 'petName') ? get(person, 'petName'):'' : '' }`}</Box>
```

Comment: need something simplified

Answer (score 0):

A javascript object is truthy, thus your code is always running get() within the ternary. To check for an empty object, try:

```
<Box>{`Pet Name: ${ ( person && Object.keys(person).length !==0 ) ? get(person, 'petName') : '' }`}</Box>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question but you answered a question that wasn't asked.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<Box>
{
`Pet Name: ${ person ? get(person, 'petName') !== null ? get(person, 'petName') : '' : '' }`
}
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Box>{`Pet Name: ${ person ? .petName ?? ' ' }`}</Box>
```